# Writing to OSX's /Library/Application Support folder throws IOException: Permission denied

Tags: java, macos, file, permissions, writefile

I'm trying to store my app's data to  /Library/Application Support/myAppFolder.

I am trying with this code (via debug)

```
String content = "This is the content to write into file";

File file = new File("/Library/Application Support/filename.txt");


            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdir();
                    file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(content);
            bw.close();

            System.out.println("Done");
```

but java.io.IOException: Permission denied is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start with...

```
if (!file.exists()) {
    file.mkdir();
    file.createNewFile();
}

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
```

You create a directory named `/Library/Application Support/filename.txt`, you then attempt to create a file named `/Library/Application Support/filename.txt` and then attempt to read said file...which is a directory...

Let's assume for the moment that you actually have read/write permissions for `/Library/Application Support`, `filename.txt` is a directory, so any attempt to treat it like a file will fail.

However,

```
File file = new File("/Library/Application Support/filename.txt");
```

should probably be...

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Library/Application Support/filename.txt");
```

This way you'll be writing to the current users home directory, which you're more likely to have read/write permissions for.

Also, your `file` should be pointing to your applications directory (not a file)

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Library/Application Support/Your Application Directory");
```

Then you could use something more like...

```
if (file.exists() || file.mkdir()) {
    file = new File(file, "filename.txt");
    file.createNewFile();
}
```

And now you can use `file` to read/write stuff to (as it now points to `filename.txt` inside `System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Library/Application Support/Your Application Directory"`)

Comment: @l'L'l Yeah, that was kind of my assumption, hence the suggestion to to use `System.getProperty("user.home")` as the prefix for the path