# Write to ~/Library/ApplicationSupport/* with java?

Tags: java, macos, finder

I'm writing an Application for Mac in Java that needs to store a few preference files. By default, they seem to be storing to the User folder, but I'd like to store the files in the Library/ApplicationSupport folder, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

I've tried `File file = new File("/Library/ApplicationSupport/AppName");` then `file.mkdir()` but it keeps returning false. I've tried adding `~` to the front of `/Library/`, and that didn't work either.

I've also tried just writing the file to the desired directory on a FileOutputStream, but no luck there either. I'm open to other ways of storing my preference files, I just don't want them stored in an obtrusive way to the user.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing to OSX's /Library/Application Support folder throws IOException: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620482/writing-to-osxs-library-application-support-folder-throws-ioexception-permiss)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write to `/Library/ApplicationSupport` because your user would not have the permission.

The plain Java io classes don't understand "~", so to write to `~/Library/ApplicationSupport`, you need:

```
System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Library/ApplicationSupport"
```

Comment: As an addenddum, ~ is a bash special character and is not interpreted if not in a shell.